# Left selection up until a certain character SQL

Tags: sql-server

My select statement returns two columns Column A is based on Column B BUT I removed the initial 17 characters. What I would then like to do is take all the characters in Column A up until it hits a \ (backslash). Can anyone help me achieve this please - current code below

```
SELECT distinct substring(Path,17,18) AS Detail, Path
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Projects]
Where [Path] like '\DATA%'
AND [Deleted] = '0'
```

Just to re-iterate as my example wasn't very clear in the comment below. I am trying to extract from the following result

```
\DATA\More Data\Even More Data\Data 1
```

To show

```
Even More Data
```

So I have removed the proceeding 17 characters until the next \

Comment: Please provide sample data and please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Just a hint: `CHARINDEX` is your friend...

Comment: charindex() will tell you the first position of a character, feed that into left() or substring().

Comment: Is the string Path always longer than 17 char?

Comment: Is the backslash always present in the "second" part of the string?

Comment: So an example would be the initial column record would read

\Data\Testing\More Data\Even More Data

What I would like to do is take everything from More Data right up until the first backslash of even more data with a result of

More Data

Comment: Sounds like you want the parent folder belonging to a file name, or just the next to last level in the directory, correct?

Answer (score 1):

For ColumnA, if you only want to take out the first 17 characters, you should use

```
RIGHT(Path, LEN(Path) - 17)
```

As your current solution will not work correctly if Path is longer than 35 characters.

As for returning the string up to the first backslash, use:

```
SELECT LEFT(Detail, CHARINDEX('\', Detail)) FirstFolder, Detail, Path
FROM 
(
    SELECT distinct RIGHT(Path, LEN(Path) - 17) AS Detail, Path
    FROM [DB].[dbo].[Projects]
    Where [Path] like '\DATA%'
    AND [Deleted] = '0'
) a
```

Or all in one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(Path, 18, CHARINDEX('\', Path, 18) - 18) 
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Projects]
WHERE [Path] like '\DATA%'
AND [Deleted] = '0'
```

This says:

- extract a substring from `path`
- start at Character 18
- The length of the string will be calculated by finding the position of the first backslash in `path` starting at Character 18, minus 18 (because we started the search on the 18th character, and we want it relative to the start of our search **not** the start of the original string)

**Update:**

As @etsa correctly points out, if you cannot guarantee that Path is at least 18 characters long and contains a backslash after character 18 ***for every row***, you should use the following to return only the rows that do meet this criteria:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(Path, 18, CHARINDEX('\', Path, 18) - 18) 
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Projects]
WHERE [Path] like '\DATA%'
AND [Deleted] = '0'
AND CHARINDEX('\', Path, 18) > 0
```

Comment: I would add (actually it was not required by the asker - i voted for your answer...) a "protection" ; something like this `WHERE LEN(PATH)>18 AND  CHARINDEX('\', PATH,17)>18`

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the length of your data, this gets the parent folder which seems to be what you want.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE ([Path] VARCHAR(256))
INSERT INTO @table VALUES
('\DATA\More Data\Even More Data\Data 1'),
('\\server\top folder\middle folder\bottom folder\file 1'),
('x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\this is what we want\x')

SELECT
    [Path]
    ,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE([Path])) as [Reverse Position of last \]
    ,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE([Path]),CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE([Path])) + 1) as [Reverse Postion of next to last \]
    ,REVERSE(
                SUBSTRING(
                    REVERSE([Path]),
                    CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE([Path]))+1,
                    CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE([Path]),CHARINDEX('\',reverse([Path]))+1)-CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE([Path])) - 1)) as [Your Desired Results]
FROM
    @table
```

**RETURNS**

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------+
|                             Path                             | Reverse Position of last \ | Reverse Postion of next to last \ | Your Desired Results |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------+
| \DATA\More Data\Even More Data\Data 1                        |                          7 |                                22 | Even More Data       |
| \\server\top folder\middle folder\bottom folder\file 1       |                          7 |                                21 | bottom folder        |
| x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\this is what we want\x |                          2 |                                23 | this is what we want |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for this but due to the potential different lengths of results, going from right to left wont work as the number of \ will be different. Where as going from left to right I will always wants the text between the third \ and fourth - hope Im making sense?

Comment: This is easily done but you did t specify this in the original post. Do you still want to see how that would work?